# Property decorator only for a specific property type

Tags: typescript, decorator

I have a property decorator in TypeScript that is only usable on properties of type `Array`. To enforce this, a `TypeError` is thrown at runtime if the property type is not `Array` (using [reflect metadata](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Decorators.md#metadata) to get property type information):

```
function ArrayLog(target: any, propertyKey: string) {
    if (Reflect.getMetadata("design:type", target, propertyKey) !== Array) {
        throw new TypeError();
    }

    // ...
}
```

However, I wouldn't consider this too dev-friendly. How could I make it so that the TypeScript compiler allows using a certain property decorator *only* on properties with a certain type?

Comment: I recognize that error you get, not sure it's relevant, but could you include that code?

Comment: @Alex A decorator with the following signature will always produce the issue, no matter tha function body: `(target: any, property: string | symbol) => PropertyDescriptor`. Changing argument types to compatible types does not help either, it's the return type that is causing trouble here. Which is strange, since returning a PropertyDescriptor is supposedly [supported](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Decorators.md#property-decorators).

Answer (score 1):

There is a little trick to achieve this:

```
function ArrayLog<K extends string, C extends { [ A in K ]: Array<any> }>(target: C, key: K) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Or even better (Just found in https://stackoverflow.com/a/47425850/274473):

```
function ArrayLog<K extends string, C extends Record<K, Array<any>>>(target: C, key: K) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Unfortunately this only works for public properties, not for private or protected properties...

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is due to the return expression missing.

Try something along the lines:

```
export function Decorator(fn:any) {
  return (target: Object, propertyKey: string, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<Array>) => {
    if (Reflect.getMetadata("design:type", target, propertyKey) !== Array) {
        throw new TypeError();
    } 
    return descriptor;
  };
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid property decorators don't take a `descriptor` argument. At least I can't find any documentation on it, and neither does the compiler allow me to do that: `Unable to resolve signature of property decorator ...`

Comment: Sorry you are right.  That is a method decorator.   I don't know if there is a solution for a property.  Perhaps you could make a getter instead of a straight property.