# Strict type checking for property type with property decorator

Tags: typescript, decorator, web-component

Is there a way to validate the type of the property that is decorated in Typescript? I would like a property decorator that only works on `boolean` class properties, but not on e.g. `string` (example below). Is this possible?

*(Note: I don't want runtime validation via reflect-metadata, just a compile type warning with Typescript.)*

```
function booleanProperty<T extends HTMLElement>(target: T, prop: string) {
  // `target` will be the class' prototype
  Reflect.defineProperty(target, prop, {
    get(this: T): boolean {
      return this.hasAttribute(prop);
    },
    set(this: T, value: boolean): void {
      if (value) {
        this.setAttribute(prop, '');
      } else {
        this.removeAttribute(prop);
      }
    }
  });
}

class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
  @booleanProperty
  foo: boolean;

  @booleanProperty
  bar: string; // TS compile error
}
customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
```

Comment: Haven't look into the handbook, but I recall there is a third argument and you may define a generic there to scope it. Just a hunch, hope that works for you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What about this?

```
function booleanProperty<
  T extends HTMLElement & Record<K, boolean>,
  K extends string>(target: T, prop: K) {
    // ... impl here
}
```

The passed-in `target` needs to be an `HTMLElement` which has a `boolean` property at the key `K`, where `K` is the type of the passed-in `prop`.  Let's see if it works:

```
class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
  @booleanProperty // okay
  foo: boolean;

  @booleanProperty // error
  bar: string;
}
```

Looks good to me.  Does that work for you?

Comment: Clever! I didn't think about narrowing down the `prop` parameter in that way.

Comment: Unfortunately this only works for public properties. Any chance this can be improved to work with protected/private properties, too?

Comment: It’s not really possible to programmatically manipulate private or protected properties because they are intentionally inaccessible from type functions like `keyof`.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a way to match the type of the property to the type of the decorator, which also **works on private fields**, and allows for specifying dataflow direction. I've created a [library](https://github.com/sorgloomer/ts-typesafe-decorators/tree/master/packages/typesafe-decorators) of it, hope it helps.

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?experimentalDecorators=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgFQJ5gKYBMAKUKayoAiGAxtAIYzRwC+cAZviHAOQzoYDOljGAWizkqNKNzYBuAFDThZADaUoGOBQB23eAGUYUYOoDmAGQiHDGKAC4UXXPkKdSFKNWgAeLfqMAadhZg2AD4ZeSUVNQhNeAAhCAgFDEp1ADVKBWAsN2tbTHsCSycRVzF3ACN4xOS-Nm4MQJC5cnDVDS04AFF1AFcQNIyssRs0PLwComdRDzZGeLY4AB92MuV5pbYVgC82GrqGmWlFSm5uOAAxeMRpODgAAV1vEzMLKDgAeje4AHkAaWu4MD6ABu1FUAA8AIwAQhsbEoa2WUlkN3uegMT3Mln+HzgAD18QTCblVBBGACHIVUHBgKd1BB4MduMBDOpKGVEnAaJyuHBSXB5FMoP9AcAQTBwQAmGFwHogMqWGQ3HHIAAWNLgCmeljgyTpMGowCiamSvPUCipmsMcC86O4yLucQSSVS6Uy2Xen1+wuBoLgYIAzNKKk7kgcUV1ev03WIPd8-jcRWLwQAWaU2oxhu4RvquwbQbGfQlF-HE3lkgUlWjqvU6k7M1ns1RcziYMvk8acb2i31ggCs0pmc0Wy1WitjUbzrwA7hBugosDqFJqpyPtpz4n4p2qyCr+RAeDL6UxgPADM2VapAR3UNI6NIgA)

```js
import { TypedPropertyDecorator } from 'typesafe-decorators';

declare const StringLogger: TypedPropertyDecorator<string, 'get'>;
declare const BooleanValidator: TypedPropertyDecorator<boolean, 'set'>;
declare const EnumValidator: TypedPropertyDecorator<'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz', 'set'>;

class Foo {
  @StringLogger // OK
  private x1!: 'a' | 'b';

  @StringLogger
  // ^^^^^^^^^^ Type of property is not assignable to type of decorator
  private x2!: number;
  // This logger annotation can only log strings

  @BooleanValidator // OK
  private x3!: boolean;

  @EnumValidator // OK
  private x4!: string;

  @EnumValidator
  // ^^^^^^^^^^^ Type of decorator is not assignable to type of property
  private x5!: 'foo' | 'bar';
  // Validator would allow 'baz' too, which does not fit into the property
}
```