# How do I force the same type on a Typescript decorator factory argument as the property it is applied to?

Tags: typescript, types, decorator

How can I make sure the argument type for the decorator factory matches the type of the property it is applied to?

```
class MyClass {
    @myDecorator("a string")
    public someProp?: string; // okay

    @myDecorator(4)
    public someProp?: number; // okay

    @myDecorator()
    public someProp?: number; // okay

    @myDecorator("a string")
    public someProp?: boolean; // error
}
```

I found [a solution that works for specific types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47425850/1186112) but I would like it to work with any property type. I can check on runtime but that doesn't seem very user friendly.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You need to make the [decorator factory](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#decorator-factories) generic in its argument, and make sure that the target and property you decorate has a compatible value type.  Here's one way to do it:

```
type KeysMatchingForWrites<T, V> = { [K in keyof T]-?: V extends T[K] ? K : never }[keyof T]

const myDecorator = <V = any>(val?: V) =>
  <T>(target: T, prop: KeysMatchingForWrites<T, V>) => {
    // impl here
    if (typeof val !== "undefined") {
      // you will need an assertion to assign anything
      target[prop] = val as any as T[KeysMatchingForWrites<T, V>];  
    }
  }
```

The type `KeysMatchingForWrites<T, V>` returns all the keys of `T` whose properties can accept a value of type `V` written to them.  So if `T` is `{narrow: "", normal: string, wide: unknown}` and `V` is `string`, then `KeysMatching<T, V>` is `"normal" | "wide"`.

Then `myDecorator()` accepts a value of type `V`, and returns a decorator whose target is some type `T`, and whose property key is of type `KeysMatchingForWrites<T, V>`.  Note that inside the implementation of `myDecorator()` you might have to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to actually do an assignment or the equivalent.  The typing above is mostly to allow people to *call* the decorator properly, not to *implement* the decorator properly.  And I also made the value optional and the `V` type default to `any` to support the case where you don't pass an argument to the decorator factory. Whether the specific typing and implementation above suits your needs has to do with your use cases; my main point here is to show that it can indeed be done.

Let's see it in action:

```
class MyClass {
  @myDecorator("a string")
  public someProp?: string; // okay

  @myDecorator(4)
  public someProp1?: number; // okay

  @myDecorator()
  public someProp2?: number; // okay

  @myDecorator("a string")
  public someProp3?: boolean; // error
  // Argument of type '"someProp3"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"someProp"'
}
```

Looks good.  The last one is an error because `@myDecorator("a string")` is expected to be applied to a property of type `string`, and the only one of those in `MyClass` is the property named `someProp`.  Since `someProp3` is not `someProp`, you get the above error.  Admittedly it would be nicer if the error message said "`boolean` is not assignable to `string`" instead, but at least it's an error in the right place.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?experimentalDecorators=true#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcCyBDYBjAFgSwHYHMAxAewCcB1U7YCBAHgBUAaKANQD4oBeKAbygDaMKHigBreMQBmUBgF0AtAH4AXGygQAHjVwATBLKFyoS2FDW4IANwikoAXwESQ02XIBQ79MVwJgUAFsQABEIb1I0Mm4oOlZolFwQdgAKKxQAG1U2AEpudncoGIYU4BRSfAhgNWYoMFJiMDU4RFQMHAISCioaehqOXK5OXgLCqAB6MZEAsHSoTFsIEcLsGWTQSFc02YBCLh4AIgBXPQgpPAhdfdzh0dGJqBdDqAB3bHTZywuoBO+EBFtgNgfFBgMRfghsPhcN9EsB2vglqNSuVKgI6g1jDwtr8YSAcQwhPBkGgsHgiGRKNRaIwWBw5ABuRH2EbM9zraAMWj+HjNYltMmdSk9Oj8XBlerPNT7fYsXBkAIZNR+KgEFivXQQNTHMRy57Q+wsZVk-L3dmyLnRfZy0gK9L7KAAHyg+3VEH2nnQ6RQfygSBAAGEvT6blAAAJBULhSKkZL7FBQI0EK4jMCHABG6Ww6ATxACEAACvUwFlE-h6eNJsQxCgQJ5CuGQmEyNHkgAWbIp9OZ7MIXMFosARiyuEOATTtnL9yrNbrYYjTYioJjHcKqYzWZzecLDQATMPR+PSJPK9XayMG5Hm0vY-HS8nV12N72t0WAMxZNPEYjpCAJY8aUh6lIEZ7gAQXKUcIFwfxXDNAByfZn37BpX32OCRAMOV-G9CEoRQDNoFBWoyhQPMaDsWDwGgBCkO3MA0PcVlPCAA)

Comment: This works great! Thank you so much! I've never seen this `[...]-?: ...` structure before. Excellent explanation too! Thanks again!

Comment: Ah I think I understand. TypeScript basically has a list of possible matches for type `V` on the target `T` and by forcing a match on `V` and the property key there should indirectly be one match left which should be the property itself. That's also why the error is a bit weird because TypeScript's best guess is that you are trying to do something with `someProp` because it's the nearest match. Works great!

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to jump in after 4 years. Yes, it is possible. There is even a way to do this on **private** properties, and since TypeScript 5.x you can even check the type of method parameters. You have to use the legacy decorators though. I've created a [library](https://github.com/sorgloomer/ts-typesafe-decorators/tree/master/packages/typesafe-decorators) that has all these helper types baked in.

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?experimentalDecorators=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgFQJ5gKYBMAKUKayoAiGAxtAIYzQA0K62OlUlIGMGUpFrNUcAL5wAZvhBwA5DEYBnSiIwBaLOSr9ZkgNwAoHarIAbFhlEBXAHZkYwCBbg910ADwULs+MgB8ACgBulIZmGABcKACUYWiYuPiEMo58Lsj0krIckl5wAGQMMcys7JzcaklQzilS6TCZujpGlLKycABiEBCIOnBwAAKJ1NA+AMzhcAD0Y3AA8gDSXXBgUMABnHAAHgCMAIRhG3AAPnAATAdwQ3XdfaUDUMPh8xNwAHovr2-d0aYQInAGTgLAZoWCDwRqyYAAcwslAARoZTDQ4DJMHBvgs4lwZPNFstqKY1kcdnAPEsLBCLujcasRBYNj55pd+vwfJIABYYQyGCCSe7dbpgDZhEnAMm0Bm9JmDNkcrk88WPN6KpVPD6MVE-P5lOCAuDA0FNSHQuEIjrIr4-MAsNgcLjisBHMIWMwgGFcMXdUYIQQ6b1AA)

```js
import { TypedPropertyDecorator, TypedParameterDecorator } from 'typesafe-decorators';

declare function Decorator<const T>(
  value: T
): TypedPropertyDecorator<T, 'set'> & TypedParameterDecorator<T, 'set'>;

class Foo {
  @Decorator(3) // OK
  private x1!: 1 | 2 | 3;

  @Decorator(3)
  // ^^^^^^^^^^  Type of decorator is not assignable to type of property
  private x2!: string;

  private fn1(
    @Decorator('hello')
    p1: string,
    @Decorator('hello')
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  Type of decorator is not assignable to type of parameter
    p2: number,
  ) {}
}
```